# Drawing to my own UIView with drawRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

Not so much to say here. Just that, no STROKE is being added to my UIView.

```
#import "DrawingLayerView.h"

@implementation DrawingLayerView

UIBezierPath *newPath;

- (void)startTouch:(CGPoint)point;
{
    [newPath moveToPoint:point];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
    [newPath stroke];
}

- (void)drawShape:(CGPoint)point
{
    [newPath addLineToPoint: point]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)endTouch:(CGPoint)point {
    [newPath removeAllPoints];
}

@end
```

`DrawingLayerView.h` is a custom class for my `UIView`.

The `drawRect` function is for sure called, but no strokes are being made.

If more information is necessary. Just tell me and I'll get it !

Comment: As danh said, you've declared `newPath` to be a global. If you want it to be an ivar, put a `{` before the declaration and a `}` after the declaration. Or better, move it to a private class extension. Or even better, make it a property (and by putting this property in a private class extension in your .m file, it will be a private property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one thing required for the code to work is the initialization of `newPath`.  On start touch: `self.newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];` (make it a property to use self.newPath, otherwise you're implicitly declaring it static).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to show how/where you are calling `drawShape`. There's nothing here that would call it. Also, assuming you are doing that, you don't appear to ever instantiate a `UIBezierPath`, e.g.:

```
- (void)startTouch:(CGPoint)point         // note, no semicolon
{
    newPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];  // note, create a `UIBezierPath` before you try to `moveToPoint`, or later, `addLineToPoint`
    [newPath moveToPoint:point];
}
```